# Plot multiple boxplots ordered by 75% quantile (Q3)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, levels

I would like to order some boxplots by the 75%-quantile of the boxplots.
Instead of the order of the x values.

I have succeeded in plotting the boxplots depending on the median.

```
 a <- c(rep("O2", 5), rep("O11", 5))
 b <- c(1300, 700, 600, 2400, 1200, 850, 1200, 1500, 999, 777)
 c <- data.frame(a,b)
 View(c)

 x3 <- c$a
 y3 <- c$b

 # Order ID from median:
 x3 <- reorder(x3, y3, FUN=median)

 ggplot(c, aes(x3, y3)) + 
   geom_boxplot()
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x4o <- reorder(x3, y3, FUN=quantile,prob=0.75)
ggplot(c, aes(x4o, y3)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```